# Angularjs: How to do two-way Data transfer of vm properties from one controller to other

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I tried to make two way data binding from parent Ctrl to child Ctrl or from child Ctrl to parent Ctrl using vm variable reference 'foo' properties. So, here I'm able to access `addToFoo()` method but 'foo' variable is not accessible and not reflecting the changes in both ctrls.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="MyApp">
        <div ng-controller="parentController as vm"
             layout="column"
             class="ng-scope">
            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.addToFoo()">
                add button
            </button>
            <span>-- {{vm.foo}} --</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="ChildController as vm"
             layout="column"
             class="ng-scope">
            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.addToFoo()">
                add button
            </button>
            <span>-- {{vm.foo}} --</span>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            angular.module('MyApp', [])
                .controller('parentController', parentController)
                .controller('childController', childController);

            function parentController($scope) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.foo = 0;
                // Updating the vm.foo when we clicked button from child or parent ctrl
                // which we wanted to see that changes in parent ctrl as well child ctrl,
                // but not working as i am expected
                vm.addToFoo = function () {
                    vm.foo += 1;
                }
            }

            function childController($scope, $controller) {
                var vm = this;
                angular.extend(vm, $controller('parentController', {$scope: $scope}));
                // Updating the vm.foo after 2sec from child ctrl. Wanted to see that
                // changes in parent ctrl and child ctrl but not working as i am expected
                setTimeout(function () {
                    vm.foo = 20;
                }, 2000);
            }
        })();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the [$timeout Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `window.setTimeout`. Only operations which are applied in the Angular execution context will benefit from Angular data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc...

Comment: See also, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Heirarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies)

Comment: this is one of the reasons that I advocate against the `as vm` ***soup***.  `vm` is **hiding** `parentController` from `ChildController` in this instance.  If you were to use `as parentVm` and `as childVm`, then `childVm` would be able to update `parentVm.foo` without issue, because `parentVm` isn't hidden by the duplicate name.  you may as well use `$scope` directly instead of `as vm` for everything.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to share data between angular modules is to use a service:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('controllerOne', controllerOne)
                         .controller('controllerTwo', controllerTwo)
                         .factory('sharedData', sharedData);

// First Controller -> sets the data
controllerOne.$inject = ['$timeout', 'sharedData'];

function controllerOne($timeout, sharedData) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.nums = [1, 2, 3];

    $timeout(initData, 3000);

    function initData() {
        sharedData.setData(vm.nums);
    }
}

// Second Controller -> reads the data
controllerTwo.$inject = ['$scope', 'sharedData'];

function controllerTwo($scope, sharedData) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = sharedData.getData();

    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return sharedData.getData();
    }, function(newData, oldData) {
        vm.data = newData;
    });
}

// Shared object
sharedData.$inject = [];

function sharedData() {
    var data = [0];
    var service = {
        setData: setData,
        getData: getData
    };
    return service;

    function setData(newData) {
        data = newData;
    }

    function getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controllerOne as ctrlOne">
        <div ng-controller="controllerTwo as ctrlTwo">
            <span>{{ctrlTwo.data}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'vm' variable is being set to the 'this' context of that particular controller. That means that scope is only accessible by that controller. One way I know how to fix this is by using a component with a controller.

```
// parent
.component('parent', {
    controller: [function ParentController() {
        var self = this;

        self.$onInit = function() {
        };

        // *demo method that can be called by the child
        self.helloFromParent = function() {
            return 'Hello from parent.';
        };
    }],
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: 'components/intercomponentCommunication/parent.html'
}

// child
.component('child', {
    controller: [function ChildController() {
        var self = this;

        self.$onInit = function() {
            // here
            self.parentCtrl.helloFromParent()
        };
    }],
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    // *requiring the parent give the child access to its scope
    require: {
        parentCtrl: '^parent'
    },
    templateUrl: 'components/intercomponentCommunication/child.html'
}
```

Here you 'require' your parent controller and therefore can access any values or functions on its scope.

Hope that helps.